# C++ UUID to stl string

Tags: c++, winapi

Trying to convert a UUID to string without boost. I have the following but assigning the wszUuid to the string guid doesn't work. Anyone know how I can do this so I can return a stl string?

```
string Server::GetNewGUID()
{
    UUID uuid;
    ::ZeroMemory(&uuid, sizeof(UUID));

    // Create uuid or load from a string by UuidFromString() function
    ::UuidCreate(&uuid);

    // If you want to convert uuid to string, use UuidToString() function
    WCHAR* wszUuid = NULL;
    ::UuidToStringW(&uuid, (RPC_WSTR*)&wszUuid);
    if (wszUuid != NULL)
    {
        ::RpcStringFree((RPC_CSTR*)&wszUuid);
        wszUuid = NULL;
    }

    string guid; 
    guid = wszUuid;            // ERROR: no operator "=" matches these operands operand types are: std::string = WCHAR*

    return guid;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Comment: I'll just point out that in the above code you're retrieving the string, immediately freeing it and nulling the pointer, and then you assign the null pointer to your std::string. Even if it compiled it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Also thee is an error with the haphazard switching between RPC_WSTR * and RPC_CSTR * typecasts. Probably old code updated for wide characters, but missed a few typecasts is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use wstring in place of string.

```
wstring  guid;
guid = wszUuid;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I'm trying to eventually get to a RakString which is a RakNet string. Is there anything wrong with doing the following? Any leaks or anything? wstring guid(wszUuid); string g(guid.begin(), guid.end()); RakString _guid = g.c_str();

Comment: Use `UuidToStringA()` instead, then you don't need to use `std::wstring` at all, and you can avoid `std::string` as well if you can pass a `char*` directly to a `RakString`. As for leaking memory, consider using `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter to call `RpcStringFree()`, or switch to [`StringFromGUID2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683893.aspx] so you can use a `char[]` on the stack.

Comment: [`StringFromGUID2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683893.aspx)

Answer (score 15):

```
string Server::GetNewGUID()
{
    UUID uuid = {0};
    string guid;

    // Create uuid or load from a string by UuidFromString() function
    ::UuidCreate(&uuid);

    // If you want to convert uuid to string, use UuidToString() function
    RPC_CSTR szUuid = NULL;
    if (::UuidToStringA(&uuid, &szUuid) == RPC_S_OK)
    {
        guid = (char*) szUuid;
        ::RpcStringFreeA(&szUuid);
    }

    return guid;
}
```